# VB.NET - Timer Every Second Monitoring Windows Application Titles

Tags: vb.net, winapi, timer

I have a VB.NET desktop application that I'm using to monitor events in another windows application running on my system.  I need to respond to certain events in a matter of seconds.  One of the events I'm monitoring instantly changes the window title of a child window within the main process (I'm not changing it, the application I'm monitoring causes the change in it's own child window title).  I have a function that uses windows API's to iterate through the title text of all the process's child windows, and I'm checking for certain values in the titles.

Is it a bad idea to be running this timer/title check once every second?  Are there performance issues associated with running a timer in windows every second 24/7? Is it also bad for performance to be calling the API's which retrieve the titles of all the application's child windows?  Could I eventually cause that application to crash by sending requests to it so often?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to benchmark it to see, but if I recall correctly, iterating through **every** window has significant overhead.

Can't you simply monitor a single window?  If you do that, you should be fine.